# AND Filter SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

AND Filter is not working.

Filter is applied on both selected date and selected value from Combo box.

```
var oVal=this.getView().byId("idUser").getValue();
var dDateStart = oEvent.getSource().getProperty('dateValue');
var dDateEnd = new Date(dDateStart + 1);
var isValidDate = oEvent.getParameter("valid");
var aFilters = [];

dDateStart.setMilliseconds(0);
dDateStart.setSeconds(0);
dDateStart.setMinutes(0);
dDateStart.setHours(0);

dDateEnd.setMilliseconds(0);
dDateEnd.setSeconds(59);
dDateEnd.setMinutes(59);
dDateEnd.setHours(23);

aFilters=[new sap.ui.model.Filter("CreatedBy",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oVal),
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("CrDate", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT, dDateStart, dDateEnd)];
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    filters: aFilters,
    and: true });
this.getView().byId("idCoTable").getBinding("items").filter(oFilter,true);
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the culprit was the `AND` by first validating the results of each filter individually, and verifying that common lines were returned for both?

Comment: Yes, Individual filters are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. 
Issue is with filtering with value instead of Key.
Thanks